# Is there any way to connect to Rational Team Concert with Perl?

Tags: java, perl, ibm-jazz

I'm using a Perl environment and trying to connect to a Rational Team Concert server to manage items and files. Right now the only alternative I have seen is a java pseudo API to connect to their services.

This is like my last option and the solution involves a mid layer (Java console application) to call console commands using Perl and reaching the RTC server this way.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Rational Team Concert, at its core, is just a bunch of REST based web services. Every single action on work items, source code, builds, or anything is just a series of web service calls. The beauty is that a web service call is not language specific! If you go out to jazz.net you can read up on how to access these web services and access them from Perl. Feel free to asks questions in the jazz.net/forums

Of course, the command line interfaces can also help as well! Check out scm and repotools.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line interface (in the `scmtools` directory of the RTC download).

There is an unsupported integration interface as well - you can start that with `scm daemon start`, but that's unsupported so you would probably be better off using the command line in the short term.